# В чем причина ошибки "'sleep' undeclared"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Enter the String: " << endl;
    cin >> str;

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++) {
        cout << str[i];
        sleep(100);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Почему на sleep(100) показывает ошибку:

```
`sleep' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Полазил везде. Вроде с библиотеками все в порядке. Так где ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо просто с большой буквы `Sleep` и всё.

Comment: такая мелкая ошибка и я не мог вникать в чем проблема. Спасибо!

Comment: Только учтите, что в sleep() (типична для \*nix) время в **секундах**, а в Sleep() (это обычно винда) **миллисекунды**.

Comment: @avp да, да. Я читал про него, так что, знаю. Только вот не обращал никак, что его надо с большой буквы писать.

Comment: При этом линуксовая находится в `unistd.h`, а та, что спит в миллисекундах, называется `usleep()`... Короче тут есть в чём поразбираться)

Comment: usleep() в **микросекундах**.

Comment: Точно, спасибо.